# Rails form_for with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a field that creates an instance of the Ranking class. It has a comment field already which sets the `params[:ranking][:comment]` but now I want to add a drop down that displays something like:

1: horrible, 2: poor, 3: mediocre, 4: good, 5: great

I would like these to set the params[:ranking][:score] to a value 1-5 so that in my create method I can do something like this:

```
 @ranking = Ranking.new( #....
                        :score => params[:ranking][:score])
```

My form looks like this right now:

```
<%= form_for([@essay, @ranking]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div classs="field">
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div classs="field">
      <%= #something here!%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I know that I need to use the `collection_select` but I haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You should just be able to use the regular `select` helper for something like that:

```
f.select :score, [['horrible', 1], ['poor', 2], ['mediocre', 3], ['good', 4], ['great', 5]]
```

You would use `collection_select` if you had a model for the scores. Something like:

```
f.collection_select :score_id, Score.all, :id, :name
```

See the API docs for [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)